# iphone sdk 4.3 - Skip through a list of images by using accelerometer

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, ios4

Firstly, I wanted to say hello to the community. I have been a passive reader for a couple of weeks and have to say that stackoverflow is a great resource to learn. Recently, I am playing around with developing small iphone apps for myself in order to learn more about the SDK.
I'm getting familiar with the basic functions right now. One of my first projects was to skip through a list of images by using my finger. I am wondering now if this is possible with the motion sensor/ accelerometer as well.

Let's assume I have 4 distinct images (image1, image2, image3, image4). I want to display the image on my iphone and show the next or previous image by tilting my iphone to the right and left.

How would I start doing that? I am not sure if this is even possible.

Thanks for your help. Have a great day

Rachel

Answer (score 1):

You can use an UIScrollView (what you assumably already did for touch control) and control it using acceleration.

In

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
```

See [UIAccelerometer and UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474061/uiaccelerometer-and-uiscrollview) here on StackOverflow.